# MCP23017 IO expander not properly pulling up signal

Tags: arduino, i2c, pullup

I'm writing firmware on a particle argon board that needs to use the MCP23017 IO expander to detect if two pins are grounded or not for a valve actuator.
The two pins are configured as

`signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_OPEN].ioExpander->pinMode(signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_OPEN].ioExpanderPin, INPUT);`
`signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_CLOSE].ioExpander->pinMode(signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_CLOSE].ioExpanderPin, INPUT);`

I have also pulled up both pins with the IO expander.

`signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_OPEN].ioExpander->pullUp(signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_OPEN].ioExpanderPin, HIGH);`
`signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_CLOSE].ioExpander->pullUp(signals[SIGNAL_VLV_1_CLOSE].ioExpanderPin, HIGH);`

I have verified both pins were mapped correctly.
When the valve actuator fully closes it grounds `SIGNAL_VLV_1_CLOSE`, and un-grounds `SIGNAL_VLV_1_OPEN`, and vice versa when the valve actuator fully opens. However when I'm testing the device, after one command of open or close the IO expander no longer properly pulls up the signal instead the signal floats around 30mV to 200mV which is not enough for the particle board to recognize it as a digital high. I also have buttons on the command module that were configured in the same way as the pins shown above, but they don't experience the same issues. What could be the possible reasons causing the IO expander to not properly pull up the signal?
[image]
[image]

Comment: A schematic would be more helpful than PCB layout zoomed and cropped to contain only the chip.

Comment: Just added the IO expander schematic.

Comment: It would help to show how the chip is connected to other devices. Zooming in on only the chip is just as helpful as showing no schematic at all.

Comment: I only added the schematic for the IO expander, the schematic for the board is separated into several schematic sheets.

Comment: the device draws too much current?

Comment: What is the relay type?

Comment: I expect your issue is with device configuration, outputs can either be open collector, weak pullup or push-pull. Please review and publish your register settings.

Comment: @Justme The relay type is signal relay. The part number is V23105A5001A201 by Axicom.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a bad ground that is causing the MCP23017 to reset. Next time that happens again, check if the port registers were reset to their power on value meaning the whole port will be set as an input instead of output.